# Duplicate one row from MySQL table but create a new auto ID and update 2 other fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the PHP code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table LIMIT 1"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
for ($i = 1; $i < mysql_num_fields($res); $i++) {
    $col_names .= mysql_field_name($res, $i).", ";
}
$col_names = substr($col_names, 0, -2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . $col_names . ") SELECT " . $col_names . " FROM $table WHERE id = $id";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$new_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

to duplicate a single record and generate a new PK upon insertion. This is working great but I also need to update 3 fields with new information on the newly created record and just wanted to check if the best approach is to use an update statement after the query has run or could there be a way to do it in the initial INSERT query? The table columns will change in the future however there are currently 20 or so columns so listing them out could be cumbersome.

Comment: you have the contents from $table from the initial query, so base your insert from that rather than another select.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? Do you mean don't do the second statement (the INSERT one).

Comment: you still need the insert, but the first query "SELECT * " gets all the data you need, so you don't need the select inside the insert.